# How can I make a ktor netty server use a CachedThreadPool to process requests?

Tags: kotlin, threadpool, ktor

Using ktor (1.4, can upgrade if needed) for a server side application, vanilla initialization:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>): Unit = io.ktor.server.netty.EngineMain.main(args)
...
fun Application.module() {
    ... stuff
}
```

I would like the underlying Netty engine to use a CachedThreadPool to process requests. Quite a few of my requests take substantial time to process (e.g. running long queries against a database), which I assume will block the thread processing the request and potentially make the server unresponsive.

How do I do that? Any other options? Do I need to make other changes (e.g. to the coroutine dispatchers) to make sure this has the desired effect?

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be something like this

```kotlin
val env: ApplicationEngineEnvironment = ....
val server = embeddedServer(Netty, env) {
    configureBootstrap = {
        group(NioEventLoopGroup(..., CachedThreadPool(..)))
    }
}

server.start(wait = true)
```

Comment: Almost. Here is the problem - in `NettyApplicatinEngine.bootstraps` they call `configureBootstrap` (which is good), but the immediately call `group(conn, worker)`, which initializes the parent and the child groups for the second time, which throws an error - group already set. :-(

Comment: Regarding my previous comment, I have filed a bug with the Ktor team => https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-2078

Comment: For the record, this has been fixed in the latest release. Works like a charm.